# Execute JOOQ query in between Flyway migration and Hibernate schema validation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jooq, flyway

My `spring-boot` application uses `Flyway` for handling database migrations and `Hibernate` as ORM. On top of that, I'd like to use JOOQ to create database views programatically with JOOQ's DSL to achieve compile-time safety. First, I'd like my Flyway migrations to complete. Then I want to run my JOOQ statement to create database views. And as a last step I'd like to run the Hibernate validation to confirm that the entities are matching the actual database schema.

However, I'm struggling with running my code at the right time. I've tried to run the JOOQ statements implemented as Flyway callbacks after migration, but that seems impossible since `DSLContext` bean has a dependency on `Flyway` bean and I'm getting an error on application startup. I've looked for any hook to execute my code before Hibernate's schema validation, but unfortunately couldn't find anything.

Is there any way to execute custom JOOQ code using `DSLContext` bean **after** Flyway migration and **before** Hibernate's schema validation?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't create the views as Flyway scripts

Comment: The views are dependent upon many columns from other tables. If someone, for instance, renames a column in one of those tables but forgets to adjust the database view, the only way to find that out is in the runtime on application startup, once migration starts. However, with JOOQ I could guarantee a compile-time safety as column rename would influence JOOQ generated classes and incorrect DSL would cause compilation failure.

Comment: But then why must this be executed before Hibernate? Do you use the View with Hibernate?

Comment: Yes, the view has its representation as Hibernate's immutable entity and is later used for some specific lookups using the `Specification` API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to this point I was trying to inject `DSLContext` as a bean into my callback classes - and as mentioned in the original question, this is impossible because of the dependency towards `Flyway` bean which is not completely initialised at the moment of callback creation:

```
@Component
class ViewInit(private val dsl: DSLContext) : Callback {
  override fun handle(event: Event, context: Context) {
    // FIXME: won't work as DSLContext bean is not fully initialised at this point
    // dsl.createView([...])
  }
}
```

However, Flyway's `Callback#handle` method signature provides a `Context` parameter that can be used to create a local `DSLContext` reusing the database connection obtained by Flyway.

```
class ViewInit : Callback {
  override fun handle(event: Event, context: Context) {
    val dsl = DSL.using(context.connection)
    // dsl.createView([...])
  }
}
```

With that setup everything runs in proper order and as expected.

An alternative solution would be to implement Flyway's `repeatable migration` as a class extending `BaseJavaMigration`:

```
class R__V0_001_CreateView : BaseJavaMigration() {
  override fun migrate(context: Context) {
    val dsl = DSL.using(context.connection)
    // dsl.createView([...])
  }
}
```